# DisplayTextField scrolling

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
private function handleJoin(connection:Connection):void{
            conexion = connection

            trace("Sucessfully connected to the multiplayer server");
            gotoAndStop(2);

            stage.addChild(ChatTextField);

            ChatTextField.width = 400;
            ChatTextField.height = 25;

            ChatTextField.x = 300
            ChatTextField.y = 400;

            ChatTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            ChatTextField.border = true

            stage.addChild(DisplayTextField);

            DisplayTextField.width = 400;
            DisplayTextField.height = 300;

            DisplayTextField.x = 300;
            DisplayTextField.y = 90;

            DisplayTextField.border = true
            DisplayTextField.scrollV += 99999
```

hello, i would like to know how to solve this problem on my chat text, it works perfectly until the end of the text as you can see here http://prntscr.com/294b1g
it doesn't show anymore what you typying?

someone knows how to make it would keep going up and show what you write? like a normal chat lobby.

Comment: So, what is the issue? That screenshot doesn't really tell what is wrong? It doesn't "scroll" the new text into view? Does it work if you manually mousewheel-scroll it? If you step with keyboard etc?

Comment: it doesn't show the next thing you write after the window is full as show the screenshot.

Comment: i want to do is http://prntscr.com/294b1g the first message when you make a new when the scrreen get fulls it goes up then "Mani :3" should desapear

Answer (score 0):

Use UIScrollBar component to enable scrollbar to your text field. Check this link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7f9c.html

Hope it helps.